# Explanation to proof of Fermat's little theorem

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Fermat's theorem:
>   For every $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, and every $p \in \mathbb{P}$.
>   Then, $a^{p}\left ( modp \right )\equiv a\left ( modp \right )$

Proof:

By the division algorithm, $a=pm+r,\exists 0\leq r< p$

Really, this is just $a\left ( modp \right )=r$ or $a \equiv r\left ( modp \right )$

Then, $a^{p} \equiv r^{p}\left ( modp \right )$ by congruency

> Suppose the non-trivial case:$r \neq 0$

Indeed, $r<p$.

However, how do I understand the fact that r is coprime to p? If I am able to understand this, I can claim that $r \in U\left ( p \right )$
where $U\left ( p \right )$ is the set of positive integers less than and coprime to p.

Edit: I wonder if this follows from Euler's theorem?

Comment: @PeterFranek Overlooked that fact. Thanks for the jolt to my memory.

Comment: "How do you understand the fact that $r$ is coprime to $p$?": I think it depends of what you mean by "$\Bbb P$" in the first line...

Comment: I corrected the typo. My mind was probably elsewhere. Take p to to be the set of all prime.
So, the only divisor of a prime p is r=1 or r=itself. But r is less than p. So, the Gcd(p,r)=1. From here we can establish that r is in U(p)